# slurm systemd wait nfs mount all folder

Tags: centos, systemd, nfs, slurm

i use slurm and i want that my deamon slurmd in systemd wait that my nfs mount.

this is my slurmd.service :

```
[Unit]
Description=Slurm node daemon
After=network.target nfs-client.target nfs-client.service
ConditionPathExists=/etc/slurm/slurm.conf

[Service]
Type=forking
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/slurmd
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/slurmd $SLURMD_OPTIONS
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
PIDFile=/var/run/slurmd.pid
KillMode=process
LimitNOFILE=51200
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
LimitSTACK=infinity

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I want that my service runs when my nfs is fully assembled. My nfs is located in /nfs
Because my network is slow and I have big nfs, I need to wait 1 minute for my nfs to be fully assembled.

because I need that slurm to write files in /nfs/slurm folder
actually, when centos start and slurmd deamon start, I have this error "/nfs/slurm no such file or folder"

I try to use PathExist parameter but not work and TimeoutStartSec but not work, my deamon run and I have this error.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Systemd has [RequiresMountsFor](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#RequiresMountsFor=).

You can add the following line to the [Unit] section of slurmd.service.

```
RequiresMountsFor=/nfs
```

Keep in mind, if you are using the resume and suspend features that your ResumeTimeout must be greater than the resume time + nfs mount time.

Answer (score 0):

Write a script that will check if the `nfs` mount is available, else `sleep` for `X` seconds. Then use this script in `ExecStartPre=` of `systemd` service file.

```
$ cat /usr/local/bin/checkNFSMount
#!/bin/bash

if [ -d /nfs/slurm ]; then
   exit 0;
else
   sleep 20;
   exit 0;
fi
```

In the `systemd` service file:

```
ExecStartPre=/usr/local/bin/checkNFSMount
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/slurmd $SLURMD_OPTIONS
```

Read about `ExecStartPre`: [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html).